# Spark Scala RDD[Row] to Dataframe - using toDF not possible

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark using Scala - When we have to convert RDD[Row] to DataFrame.
Why we have to convert the RDD[Row] to RDD of case classor RDD of tuple in order to use rdd.toDF()
Any specific reason it was not provided for the RDD[Row]

```
object RDDParallelize {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]")
  .appName("learn")
  .getOrCreate()

val abc = Row("val1","val2")
val abc2 = Row("val1","val2")
val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(abc,abc2))
import spark.implicits._
rdd1.toDF() //doesn't work
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove `Row` from `abc` and `abc2`, you should use Tuples: `val abc = Row("val1", "val2")`

Comment: @vilalabinot but why we have to convert it to a Tuple. Whats reason why its not implemented like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is confusing since there are implicit conversion for the toDF methode.
Like you may have seen, toDF is not a methode of Rdd class, but it is defined in DatasetHolder, you are using rddToDatasetHolder in SQLImplicits to convert the rdd you created to a DatasetHolder. if you look into the methode rddToDatasetHolder,

```
implicit def rddToDatasetHolder[T : Encoder](rdd: RDD[T]): DatasetHolder[T] = {
DatasetHolder(_sqlContext.createDataset(rdd))
```

}

you will see that it requires an Encoder of T which is

> Used to convert a JVM object of type T to and from the internal Spark
> SQL representation.

if you try to convert a Rdd[Row] to Datasetholder you will need one encoder to tell spark how you convert Row object to internal SQL representation. However

> Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case " +
> "classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types " +
> "will be added in future releases

spark does not have any encoder for Row type so such conversion never finished successfully.